# tem como executar uma query dentro de uma função definida pelo usuario em php?

Tags: php, mysql

tenho código assim:

```
function apagar(){

    $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','usuario','senha');
    $db = mysqli_select_db("banco");    

    $delete = mysqli_query("TRUNCATE table sap_reportes.zempe019");
    return $delete;

    //return 'teste';
}

//script do relatório.

apagar($delete);

//fim do relatório.
```

o problema é que o Truncate não funciona, estou rodando esse script no cmd, esse script server para gerar relatórios até ai tudo bem ele esta gerando o relatório normal e esta enviando por e-mail o problema é que no final do relatório gostaria de apagar a tabela já tentei de tudo mais não sei porque o truncate não funciona depois de rodar todo o script no começo do script ele até funciona mais precisaria que esse truncate executasse no final do relatório por isso eu fiz essa função em php e chamei ela no fim do relatorio.

Comment: Sim é possível, qual erro acontece?

Comment: O primeiro argumento do `mysqli_query()` é a conexão, aparentemente por isso não funciona.

Comment: Tente assim `$delete = mysqli_query($conexao, "TRUNCATE table sap_reportes.zempe019") or die(mysqli_error($conexao));`

Comment: Apareceu algum erro?

Comment: Um delete sem where funciona?

Comment: Tem algum erro sendo retornado vc precisa descobrir ele ou tentar rodar essa consulta direto no banco veja via phpmyadmin ou workbench

Comment: Sim, qualquer tipo de encapsulamento é possível.

Comment: conseguir resolver assim $apagar = mysql_query("truncate table nome_da_tabela");

Comment: e chamei $apagar(); no fim do relatório funcionou

Comment: `mysql_query()` é uma função removida nas versões novas do php e `mysqli_query()` é a função atual.

Answer (score -1):

Para fazer um encapsulamento, eu prefiro usar PDO:

```
 class Database {

        private static $servidor = 'localhost'; // Servidor, no caso poderia ser também localhost
        private static $usuario = 'root'; // usuário do banco de dados
        private static $senha = 'senha'; // senha do banco de dados
        private static $banco = 'banco'; // nome do banco de dados
        private static $instance = null;

        public static function getConnection() {
            if (!self::$instance instanceof PDO) {
                try {
                    self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' .
                    self::$servidor . ';dbname=' . 
                    self::$banco, 
                    self::$usuario, 
                    self::$senha);
                } catch (PDOException $exc) {
                    echo "Erro ao conectar :: {$exc->getMessage()}";
                }
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        public function fetchAll($query) {
            $con = self::getConnection();

            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

            $this->execute($stmt);

            if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
                return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function execute(PDOStatement $stmt, array $data = null) {
            try {
                if (isset($data)) {
                    $stmt->execute($data);
                } else {
                    $stmt->execute();
                }
            } catch (PDOException $exc) {
                echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
            }
        }

        public function action($sql, array $data) {
            $con = self::getConnection();
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $this->execute($stmt, $data);
            if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

$conexao = new Database();

//listando...
$collection = $conexao->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM tabela");

foreach ($collection as $data) {
      echo $data['campo'] . '<br>';
}

//deletando...
 $deletou = $conexao->action('DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id=:id',array('id' => (int) $id));
 if ($deletou) {
   echo "apagou!";
 }

//inserindo
$insert = $conexao->action("INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) values (:campo1,:campo2)",array('campo1'=>'valor1','campo2'=>'valor2'));
 if ($insert) {
   echo "gravou!";
 }
//atualizando
$update = $conexao->action("UPDATE tabela SET campo1=:campo1, campo2=:campo2 where id=:id",array('campo1'=>'valor1','campo2'=>'valor2','id' => (int) $id));
 if ($update) {
   echo "atualizou!";
 }
```

Comment: Na minha opinião, não esta sendo muito claro em que ponto isso tudo soluciona o problema relatado na pergunta.